# What program offers automated image resizing?

Tags: windows, image-processing, automation

I have a blog. Before I upload images from my computer (these images are really big), I want to resize them (make them smaller) and save them in a different folder.

After that, I can upload them.

How can I automate this process to avoid opening every image in an editor and doing it manually? This is getting annoying.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[IrfanView](http://www.irfanview.com/) has a very powerful batch conversion / resize / renaming tool and allows you to save them in a different folder.

It remembers your last used settings, but you can also Save/Load settings as well.

### How To

From the File menu > "Batch Conversion/Rename..." - you are presented with the main "Batch conversion" dialog box:

[image: Batch Conversion Dialog]

1. Select either "Conversion", "Rename" or both.
2. Select the source files
3. Set the output format
4. Set Advanced options (Resize, Crop, and many other options - **SCREENSHOT BELOW**)
5. Set the rename (output filename) options (defaults to same filename as the source image `$N`)
6. Set where you want to save the files
7. **Go!**

The "Advanced" options dialog (at stage 4 above) allows you to set the resize, crop options etc.
[image: Advanced options dialog]

1. Resize options
   (You don't need to touch the other options if you don't want to.)
2. Ok

Yes, there are a lot of options (it does *everything*!), but you can probably ignore most of them after a cursory glance. It works very well in my opinion.

Comment: Yet another question Answered (correctly) by infaview. I think it is winning.

Answer (score 3):

I've used [Caesium](http://caesium.sourceforge.net/) for a few years now and have found it quite stable and easy to use. It is primarily an image compressor, but it also features resizing functionality by both absolute pixel values and a relative percentage. Resizing is turned off by default but it is very easy to enable and customize directly from the main window.

It allows selection of images by directory (and optionally all subdirectories) or by selecting images manually, and then running the compression and/or resizing on any or all images selected.

While it is primarily an image compressor, if you aren't interested in compressing the images at all you can just set quality to 100%, although using a quality of even just 95% can sometimes reduce the file size (and thus your bandwidth to serve the file) by over 50% without any obviously visible loss of quality.

It can also automatically strip out EXIF data to further minimize file size, and possibly reduce the risk of sharing personal data (such as GPS coordinates which some cameras can record), if it is photos you are uploading.

Answer (score 3):

I already was in the same situation. I resolve it with [FastStone Resizer](http://www.faststone.org/FSResizerDetail.htm).

Your requirement are covered :

- You can **rename** your images with some options (target directory, original name, time information, sequential number, upper/lower case, sorting, ...)
- **Re-sizing** tool (% or pixel based, ratio-preserved or not, ...)
- **Windows** software

Other functionality provided :

- You can at the same time **convert** your images (format, quality, ...)
- You can make other image editions like **rotate** them, **crop** them, change the color depth, the DPI, add a text, a border, ...
- I appreciate its **portable version** because I need it for very
  occasional use. An installable version is also provided.
- This tool is **free** and very **light**

Tell me if you have any questions.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [ImageMagick](https://imagemagick.org/script/download.php) (Free, open source, cross-platform, CLI): `mogrify -resize 30x30% *.png` (will resize all PNGs in current folder to 30% horizontally and vertically in this example)

Answer (score 1):

[Bulk Resize Photos](http://bulkresizephotos.com):

- Nothing to download or install.
- Images don't get uploaded. All the images are resized in your browser. (fast **and** private)
- Works offline after your first visit.

The resized photos are saved in a zip file, which you could then unzip into a different folder.

Answer (score 1):

Many years ago I was trying to find the best image batching software. At that time I chose EyeBatch (by Atalasoft) as the winner. It is not developed anymore but as it is still very powerful I thought it is worth mentioning. You can even edit the workflow while you get a nondestructive preview.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you are on Windows 10, you can download and install [Microsoft
PowerToys](https://github.com/microsoft/PowerToys) which is an open source program from Microsoft which contains many useful utilities. One of those utilities is a batch image resizer.

After you install PowerToys, you can right click a selection of files and click "Resize pictures" from the context menu to open the Resizer dialog to select your resize options. You can also drag and drop the files with the right mouse button and click "Resize pictures here" from the context menu to have the resized files appear in a folder of your choice.

Here is a page with more information on the Resizer utility: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/powertoys/image-resizer

Note: PowerToys is currently in a pre-release state but it seems pretty stable from my experience with it.